# Центрирование содержимого ячеек GridView в Android OS

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Почитал методы, перечитал пример в книге, порыскал на форумах, сам не допер. Как сделать выравнивание содержимого (строка текста) в каждой ячейке виджета GridView по центру? 
Это должна быть комбинация неких параметров в .xml-файле разметки запускаемой гридовой Activity или это делается программно в классе? Возможно ли это вообще, т.к. надобность такой задачи вполне оправданная.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте поиграть с [android:gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:gravity). Это свойство, которое определяет расположение объекта внутри каждой ячейки по вертикальной и горизонтальной оси. Например так:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    ...
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотрели вот [сюда](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)?
Может помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Как [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141910/android-center-gridview-horizontally) можете использовать одинаковые отступы при помощи android:layout_margin в файле разметки